Referrer on multiple redirects?
I'm attempting to validate the referrer for certain requests in my Rails application. I expect there to be cross-origin requests, but I want to limit which origins are valid - including on redirects if possible.
I'm using Cognito for authorization, so during the login flow the user redirects to my server's oauth2/login endpoint and then it redirects to Cognito. After authentication, Cognito redirects back to my server, and my server redirects back to the client application.
However, what I noticed is that when my login callback handler is invoked (by Cognito redirecting to it) is that request.referrer is either set to the original client referrer value or else to the idp's server, if the user needed to re-authenticate with them! Never is the referrer set to Cognito's domain?!
Is this usual behavior? Or is Cognito trying to mask the User Pool Domain from the request for security purposes? Is there a way to tell who the immediately previous referrer was in series of redirects?

The elefant in the room here is that the referrer header is not a reliable way of certifying where the request originated from. It's completely up to the client if they want to send it and it's easily spoofed. If your goal is to redirect the user back after authentication you should store the url in the session or pass it along as a query string parameter in the callback url. I haven't used Cognito but it's usually possible in most oauth style setups.

@max I am of course sending encrypted state information along to Cognito that gets sent back to me, and I use that for redirection purposes. I was more just wanting to validate that my callback url had been redirected to by Cognito and not by something else. It's not overly important at the end of the day to be able to verify the referrer, but it is annoying that I can't!

Alright but as I wrote the origin header isn't a reliable indicator as it's trivial to spoof it. That's why Rails for example uses anti-csrf tokens. Check the documentation of the provider if they offer any such feature to verify the response.

@max I'm using CSRF tokens, a PKCE challenge, Nonce where applicable, etc. I was never intending to rely purely on the Origin or Referer (in this case) Headers for security. That said, the Origin header is more reliable than Referer and can be meaningfully used for security. While easy to spoof, spoofing it doesn't get you anything unless you can fool the user's browser into accepting the spoofed Origin such that it passes along the user's session cookies. Validating the Referrer is just a nice to have for me.
